# data getting remove when reindexing

Tags: python, pandas

What am I doing wrong? I do not want to lose data when reindexing but simply want to extend my dataframe with missing dates so I can practice interpolation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0,1,2], 'date':[pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01'),
                                         pd.to_datetime('2020-04-01'),
                                         pd.to_datetime('2022-04-01')]})   

df = df.set_index('date')['value']
df 
value
0   2017-04-01
1   2020-04-01
2   2022-04-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

then I add expand the dataframe but the data is missing:

```
date = pd.date_range(start='2015-03-01', end='2050-01-01', freq='M')
full_data = df.reindex(date).fillna(0)
```

all the items in the dataframe become `NaN`

I want the date to expand for monthly observations and then I want it to include my data from the first data frame with the remaining being `NaN`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Expending a dataframe should be done with conct function

Comment: @gtomer what do you mean? I'm not clear?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use Month Start frequency

```py
date = pd.date_range(start='2015-03-01', end='2050-01-01', freq='MS')
```

Comment: but when I merge it's NaN even for the days I have data

Comment: using above code, just add this - 
date = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2018-01-01', freq='MS')
df_w_nulls = df.reindex(date)

It will show it's all nan

Comment: @Lostsoul Couldn't reproduce, what's your pandas version.

Comment: I'm using colab and it's 1.3.5

Comment: @Lostsoul What do you mean by `add this`? Is the df same with your example not after your originally reindexed?

Comment: it is the same, I just replaced my date = lines with what you had above.

Comment: @Lostsoul Not sure what happens to you, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxxAO.png) is the output of mine. 2017-04-01 is 0 because original it is 0.

Comment: The answer given by @Ynjxsjmh is correct-- should be accepted.